# What is the purpose of "new Function()", especially as an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm working a task to remove some JSHint warnings in our build. In particular, I'm getting rid of instances of "`new Function()`", because they're [essentially `eval` statements](http://jslinterrors.com/the-function-constructor-is-eval/).

I've run across a strange pattern in our code that I don't understand and am reluctant to change until I know what it does. Here's an example:

```
if(typeof(someObj.someProperty) === "string"){
someObj.someProperty = new Function("return " + someObj.someProperty + " ;")();
}
```

Neither I nor my coworkers can figure out what exactly this is supposed to accomplish. The best we can come up with is that it's some kind of attempt at cloning the property when it's a string. Nobody at all can figure out why it's declared as an IIFE.

Is this a pattern that anyone else has seen? If it is a clone, does it even matter for strings since they're immutable?

Comment: No; it's just evaling the property.

Comment: I doesn't clone the property. if `someProperty` was `"2 + 2"` the the new function would return `4`.

Comment: it's just as you said in the first paragraph, it's essentially an `eval` statement.

Comment: That would convert the string to some other type, or give a syntax error if the value  couldn't be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like someone heard they shouldn't use `eval`, and decided to follow the letter of that advice but not the spirit. In other words, it is more or less equivalent to:

```
if (typeof(someObj.someProperty) === "string") {
    someObj.someProperty = eval(someObj.someProperty);
}
```

To be precise, it is exactly equivalent to:

```
if (typeof(someObj.someProperty) === "string") {
    someObj.someProperty = eval("(function () { return " + someObj.someProperty + "; })")();
}
```

This is still quite unsafe and all the caveats against `eval` apply equally well here.

Comment: After more digging, this is exactly the case. These used to be `eval()` statements. What's really happening here is that the code is looking up objects by their namespace and name; sort of a poor man's reflection. It's not a very readable or maintainable pattern.

Comment: @Chad: Not at all! You should parse the string and do all the look-ups explicitly. Will allow for nicer error messages too